# Creating chapters by referencing parts of other chapters

Tags: chapters

I am trying to create a chapter or a section by referencing some parts of other sections.

For example:

> “He goes to school”

Here “school” can be

- Business school,
- Law school,
- etc.

> “She is going to watch a movie”

Here movie can be

- romantic/comedy
- horror,
- sci-fi,
- etc.

So here, I want to reference school and movie, so that they come up in a new chapter or section, like this

1. school - Business school, Law school, etc.
2. movie - romantic/comedy, horror, sci-fi, etc.
3. …

Since there are lot of these, doing it manually is tedious.

Is there any way of doing this automatically using some commands?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but how about defining `\newcommand{\School}{Business school}`, and using `\School` instead of `school`. The,n when you need a different version you redefine it with `\renewcommand{\School}{Law school}` to change the definition?  I would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up how you actually want to use this.  This will help to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PeterGrill sounds like an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, but since at least two of us have a similar interpretations I am converting my comment to an answer.

You should define macros for each of the components that may change, and then use the values of these macros as needed.

---

### Method 1:

Using the example you gave, for instance you could define the macro `\School` to contain the school type, and use that in the sentence.  So, here I initialize an empty value of `\School` and the sentence it is going to be used in:

```
\newcommand*{\School}{}
\newcommand*{\SchoolSentence}{He goes to \School.}
```

So, whenever you want to use this, you first ensure that the value of `\School` is set before using `\SchoolSentence`:

```
\renewcommand*{\School}{Business School}
\SchoolSentence

\renewcommand*{\School}{Harvard Law School}
\SchoolSentence
```

which produces

> He goes to Business School.
>
> He goes to Harvard Law School.

You can construct expressions with more variables as well.  For instance:

```
\newcommand*{\Movie}{}
\newcommand*{\Person}{}
\newcommand*{\MovieSentence}{\Person\ is going to watch \Movie.}
```

The you can use this as:

```
\renewcommand*{\Person}{Uncle Owen}
\renewcommand*{\Movie}{The Empire Strikes Back}
\MovieSentence
```

> Uncle Owen is going to watch The Empire Strikes Back.

### Notes:

- The trailing backslash in `\Person\`   was needed to ensure that there is a space following the value of this macro.

---

### Method 2:

An alternate way of approaching this is to treat the school name as a parameter. So, the `\SchoolSentence` would be defined as accepting one parameter (the `[1]`), and to using `#` access the value of the first parameter:

```
\newcommand*{\SchoolSentence}[1]{He goes to #1.}
```

Similarly we can defined `\MovieSentence` to require two parameters:

```
\newcommand*{\MovieSentence}[2]{#1 is going to watch #2.}
```

The using this as follows yields results identical to above:

```
\SchoolSentence{Business School}

\SchoolSentence{Harvard Law School}

\MovieSentence{Uncle Owen}{The Empire Strikes Back}
```

---

### Code (Method 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\School}{}
\newcommand*{\SchoolSentence}{He goes to \School.}

\newcommand*{\Movie}{}
\newcommand*{\Person}{}
\newcommand*{\MovieSentence}{\Person\ is going to watch \Movie.}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\School}{Business School}
\SchoolSentence

\renewcommand*{\School}{Harvard Law School}
\SchoolSentence

\renewcommand*{\Person}{She}
\renewcommand*{\Movie}{The Shinning}
\MovieSentence

\renewcommand*{\Person}{Uncle Owen}
\renewcommand*{\Movie}{The Empire Strikes Back}
\MovieSentence

\end{document}
```

---

### Code (Method 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\SchoolSentence}[1]{He goes to #1.}
\newcommand*{\MovieSentence}[2]{#1 is going to watch #2.}

\begin{document}
\SchoolSentence{Business School}

\SchoolSentence{Harvard Law School}

\MovieSentence{She}{The Shinning}

\MovieSentence{Uncle Owen}{The Empire Strikes Back}
\end{document}
```